# call "registerForRemoteNotificationTypes" after registration

Tags: ios, push-notification, call

I want to call "registerForRemoteNotificationTypes" after registration on my app. Many app on App Store have this realization. But I don't know how to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: didn't get..? Can you elaborate in brief .?

Comment: I want implement "apple alert view" in another view controller